# How to get calendar Quarter from a date in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have different dates in a column.  For example:

```
20080102
20070821
```

I want to convert these dates in Year and calendar quarter.  E.g.,

```
Year      Quarter
2008      2008-Q1
2007      2007-Q3
```

I can get the first column with:

```
select left(date,4) as year from table
```

How can I produce the second column?

Comment: What is the datatype of your column?

Comment: datatype for the date column is int

Comment: Since you are storing the data incorrectly, the first thing you need to do is to check for invalid dates and fix them. It is a very poor idea to store dates as integers.

Comment: @HLGEM blimey - our data warehouse is based on  DateKeys as integers. Never really questioned having to covert them to char(8) all the time! [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c4b5/2)

Answer (score 136):

```
SELECT DATEPART(QUARTER, @date)
```

This returns the quarter of the `@date`, assuming `@date` is a `DATETIME`.

Comment: The OP states that the column is of type `INT`, not `DATETIME`.  This will not work for them.

Comment: I had not seen that. I was looking for a solution to this for a DATETIME type, and did not see this anywhere on here. I put it here for anyone else looking for Quarter on a date who does have a datetime object.

Comment: This also returns the 1, 2, 3, or 4 only, not `2008-Q1` requested in the OP. There doesn't appear to be a succinct way to achieve what the OP asked.

Comment: Clearly OP had figured out the year part already. So beyond that you just need to know (or be able to google) how to concat strings in sql.  `SELECT CONCAT(DATEPART(year, @date), '-', DATEPART(QUARTER, @date))`

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT DATENAME(Quarter, CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), datecolumn) AS DATETIME))
```

Comment: SELECT DATENAME(Quarter, CONVERT(datetime, mycolumn )) 
from Mytable                                                              This throws an error
--Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I do it.  Pretty brief and doesn't rely on temp tables.

```
CAST(year(TheDate) AS char(4)) + '-Q' + 
CAST(CEILING(CAST(month(TheDate) AS decimal(9,2)) / 3) AS char(1))
```

As an example:

```
SELECT convert(char(10), getdate(), 101) AS TheDate, 
CAST(year(getdate()) AS char(4)) + '-Q' + 
    CAST(CEILING(CAST(month(getdate()) AS decimal(4,2)) / 3) AS char(1)) AS SelectQuarter
```

This will return:

```
TheDate    SelectQuarter
---------- -------------
07/10/2013 2013-Q3
```

Obviously the string itself can be changed to suit your own format.  Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I did it like this (I am using SQL Server):

```
SELECT 'Q' + cast(DATEPART(QUARTER, GETDATE()) as varchar(1)) + ' - ' + cast(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) as varchar(4)) AS 'Date Quarter'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your date field data is in `int` you will need to convert it to a datetime:

```
declare @date int
set @date = 20080102

SELECT Datename(quarter, Cast(left(@date, 4) + '-' 
    + substring(cast(@date as char(8)), 5, 2) + '-' 
    + substring(cast(@date as char(8)), 7, 2) as datetime)) as Quarter
```

or

```
SELECT Datename(quarter, Cast(left(@date, 4) + '-' 
    + substring(cast(@date as char(8)), 5, 2) + '-' 
    + right(@date, 2) as datetime)) as quarter
```

Then if you want the `Q1` added:

```
SELECT left(@date, 4) + '-Q' + Convert(varchar(1), Datename(quarter, Cast(left(@date, 4) + '-' 
    + substring(cast(@date as char(8)), 5, 2) + '-' 
    + right(@date, 2) as datetime))) as quarter
```

My advice would be to store your `date` data as a `datetime` so then you do not need to perform these conversions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option. Use a CTE to define the months of the quarter and then join to it to determine the quarter:

```
WITH Quarters AS (
   SELECT Q = 'Q1', MonthBegin = 1, MonthEnd = 3 UNION
   SELECT Q = 'Q2', MonthBegin = 4, MonthEnd = 6 UNION
   SELECT Q = 'Q3', MonthBegin = 7, MonthEnd = 9 UNION
   SELECT Q = 'Q4', MonthBegin = 10, MonthEnd = 12
)
SELECT
   [Year] = DATEPART(yyyy, CONVERT(DATETIME, Dates.[date])),
   [Quarter] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(yyyy, CONVERT(DATETIME, Dates.[date]))) + '-' + q.Q
FROM
   (VALUES
       ('20080102'),
       ('20070821')
   ) AS Dates ([date])
   INNER JOIN Quarters q ON
      DATEPART(m, CONVERT(DATETIME, Dates.[date])) >= q.MonthBegin AND
      DATEPART(m, CONVERT(DATETIME, Dates.[date])) <= q.MonthEnd;
```

Returns:

```
Year  Quarter
----- ----------
2008  2008-Q1
2007  2007-Q3
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5660/0)

Handle column type of int (04/23/2014):

```
WITH Quarters AS (
    SELECT Q = 'Q1', MonthBegin = 1, MonthEnd = 3 UNION
    SELECT Q = 'Q2', MonthBegin = 4, MonthEnd = 6 UNION
    SELECT Q = 'Q3', MonthBegin = 7, MonthEnd = 9 UNION
    SELECT Q = 'Q4', MonthBegin = 10, MonthEnd = 12
)
SELECT
    [Year] = DATEPART(yyyy, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Dates.[date]))),
    [Quarter] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(yyyy, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Dates.[date])))) + '-' + q.Q
FROM
    (VALUES
        (20080102),
        (20070821)
    ) AS Dates ([date])
    INNER JOIN Quarters q ON
        DATEPART(m, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Dates.[date]))) >= q.MonthBegin AND
        DATEPART(m, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Dates.[date]))) <= q.MonthEnd;
```

Comment: i think when you do one more "denormalize" the quarter table and have a row for each month (1: Q1, 2: Q1, 3: Q1, 4: Q2, ... ) then you can direct join the month and not need a < and >

Comment: you can also use the BETWEEN operator instead of <= and >=

Answer (score 2):

Assuming field data type INT and field name "mydate".
In the OP question, the INT date values when converted to string are ISO date literals.

```
select DatePart(QUARTER, cast(cast(mydate as char(8)) as date))
```

You can use datetime if using older server version.

Answer (score 2):

To get the exact output you requested, you can use the below:

```
CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, @Date) AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' - Q' + CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER, @Date) AS NVARCHAR(10))
```

This will give you an outputs like:
"2015 - Q1", "2013 - Q3", etc.

Answer (score 1):

nice excuse to muck around with CONVERT. Probably prettier ways of doing it:

[live test on SQLfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dcf64/1)

```
create table the_table 
(
  [DateKey] INT,
)

insert into the_table
values
(20120101),
(20120102),
(20120201),
(20130601)


WITH myDateCTE(DateKey, Date) as
  (
    SELECT 
      DateKey
      ,[Date] = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8),DateKey),112) 
    FROM the_table
   )

SELECT 
  t.[DateKey]
  , m.[Date]
  , [QuarterNumber] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),Datepart(qq,Date))
  , [QuarterString] = 'Q' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),Datepart(qq,Date))
  , [Year] = Datepart(yyyy,Date) 
  , [Q-Yr] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),'Q' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),Datepart(qq,Date))) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),Datepart(yyyy,Date))  
FROM 
  the_table t
  inner join myDateCTE m
    on 
    t.DateKey = m.DateKey
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   Q.DateInQuarter,
   D.[Year],
   Quarter = D.Year + '-Q'
      + Convert(varchar(1), ((Q.DateInQuarter % 10000 - 100) / 300 + 1))
FROM
   dbo.QuarterDates Q
   CROSS APPLY (
      VALUES (Convert(varchar(4), Q.DateInQuarter / 10000))
   ) D ([Year])
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca50a/1)

Comment: can you tell me what will bee the calculation for 11_2015 this type of input?

Comment: @SaNa3819 Please ask a new question. This answer is in response to an `int` column. It can't accept string input. You're barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT  CONCAT (TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY-'),concat ('Q',TO_CHAR(sysdate,'Q') ))from dual
```

Replace `sysdate` with your own column name with date type format and `dual` with your table name

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the integer to a char(8) then a datetime. 
then wrap that in 
SELECT DATEPART(QUARTER, [date])

You will then have to convert the above to character and add on the '-' + year (also converted to char)

The arithmetic overflow above is caused by omitting the initial convert to a character type.

I would be inclined to abstract the conversion to date-time using views where possible and then use the quarter function and character conversion as and when required.

Answer (score 0):

Here you see one of the more alternatives :

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN @TODAY BETWEEN @FY_START AND DATEADD(M, 3, @FY_START) THEN 'Q1'
         WHEN @TODAY BETWEEN DATEADD(M, 3, @FY_START) AND DATEADD(M, 6, @FY_START) THEN 'Q2'
         WHEN @TODAY BETWEEN DATEADD(M, 6, @FY_START) AND DATEADD(M, 9, @FY_START) THEN 'Q3'
         WHEN @TODAY BETWEEN DATEADD(M, 9, @FY_START) AND DATEADD(M, 12, @FY_START) THEN 'Q4'
       END
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the function `MONTH` which returns the month as a number, we can easily calculate the quarter.

```
select date, CEILING((MONTH(date) * 4) / 12) quarter from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @TempTable table([Date] datetime)

insert into @TempTable([Date])
values('2008-01-02'),('2007-08-21')
                      
select datepart(year, [Date]) as [year]
,convert(varchar(10),datepart(year, [Date])) + '-Q' + convert(varchar(3),datename(quarter, [Date])) as quarter_with_year
,datefromparts(datepart(year, [Date]),(convert(varchar(3),datename(quarter, [Date])) * 3)-2,1) as quarter_startdate
,eomonth(datefromparts(datepart(year, [Date]),convert(varchar(3),datename(quarter, [Date])) * 3,1)) as quarter_enddate
FROM @TempTable
```

> This returns the year,quarter, and start end date of quarter.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  your_date, 
  CONCAT (TO_CHAR(your_date, 'YYYY-'),concat ('Q', date_part(quarter, your_date) ))
from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE     @QuarterVar TINYINT
SELECT      @QuarterVar = ( ( ( DATEPART( month, GETDATE( ) ) - 1 ) / 3 ) + 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone,looking for a way to get date from and date to for each quarter

```
declare @sdate date = '2022-02-01'
    , @edate date = '2023-12-31';

with dates_CTE (cDate) as (
    select @sdate
    Union ALL
    select DATEADD(day, 1, cDate)
    from dates_CTE
    where cDate < @edate
)

select min( cDate) dateFrom,max(cDate) dateTo,  min(DATEPART(QUARTER, cDate))q, min(YEAR(cDate)) qYear, CONCAT(YEAR(cDate),'-Q', DATEPART(QUARTER, cDate)) qName
from dates_CTE
group by DATEPART(QUARTER, cDate), YEAR(cDate)
option (maxrecursion 1000)
```

Sample out put

| dateFrom | dateTo | q | qYear | qName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 | 2022-03-31 | 1 | 2022 | 2022-Q1 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022-06-30 | 2 | 2022 | 2022-Q2 |
| 2022-07-01 | 2022-09-30 | 3 | 2022 | 2022-Q3 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2022-12-31 | 4 | 2022 | 2022-Q4 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-03-31 | 1 | 2023 | 2023-Q1 |
| 2023-04-01 | 2023-06-30 | 2 | 2023 | 2023-Q2 |
| 2023-07-01 | 2023-09-30 | 3 | 2023 | 2023-Q3 |
| 2023-10-01 | 2023-12-31 | 4 | 2023 | 2023-Q4 |

Answer (score -3):

Try the following:

```
CONCAT(datepart(yyyy,DATE),'-', DATEPART(qq,DATE))
```

It returns:

```
yyyy-q
```

Example: `2017-3` for `2017-07-11`