# grouping in sql server with for xml

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in the following format

```
reporting_date  interest_payment  balance
200401          10                  10
200402          20                  15
200403          30                  20
200404          40                  30
200405          50                  40
200406          60                  50
200407          70                  60
```

i wanted to generate an OUTPUT in the following format :

The output of the query should look like this :

```
reporting_date  interest_payment   balance
Q1 -2004          60                 10
Q2 -2004          150                30 
Q3 -2004          70                 60
Q4 -2004          0                   0
```

i.e i wanted to represent data by quarter and year and group by quarter and year for interest_payment column but for balance i need to pick up the value from the first reporting date in that quarter ,so as you can see q1-2004 has 10,15 and 20 but only 10 is accounted as that was the first reporting date in that quarter

I have my query working for interest payment but i am not sure how do i pickup the first reporting value for balance in a quarter

```
SELECT report_year as "@date",'Q'+CAST(report_quarter+1 as varchar(1)) as "@quarter",  SUM(a.balance) as "@balance", SUM(a.interest_payment) as "@interest_payment"
         FROM (SELECT *,
         (reporting_date%100 - 1)/3 as report_quarter,
         reporting_date/100 as report_year 
         FROM  employee) a  
         GROUP by report_year, report_quarter
         order by report_year, report_quarter
```

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141100/how-to-get-quarter-from-a-date-in-tsql

Comment: my query is more about how to pick up the balance amount from the first reporting date in a quarter . i am already able to group by data by quarter as mentioned in the link

Comment: You will need to use `ROW_NUMBER`. If you use 2012 (and higher) see http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/10/sql-server-over-clause-with-first-_value-and-last_value-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012-rows-between-unbounded-preceding-and-unbounded-following/

Comment: i tried this approach using your suggestion :
SELECT report_year, 'Q'+cast(report_quarter+1 as varchar(1))
    ,first_value(balance) OVER(PARTITION BY report_year,report_quarter order by report_year,report_quarter) AS Total
from 
(
    select 
        *,
        (reporting_date%100 - 1)/3 as report_quarter,
        reporting_date/100 as report_year
    fromemployee
) T
But still i dont get the expected ouput

Comment: Should `interest_payment` for Q2 be `150 = 40 + 50 + 60`?

Comment: yes it should be 150 ,sorry abt the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create all combination of years and quarters. Then use window functions such AS `SUM OVER()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` for the `interest_payment` and `balance`.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(
    reporting_date      INT,
    interest_payment    INT,
    balance             INT
)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES
(200401, 10, 10), (200402, 20, 15), (200403, 30, 20),
(200404, 40, 30), (200405, 50, 40), (200406, 60, 50),
(200407, 70, 60);

;WITH quarters(yr, qtr) AS(
    SELECT
        y.N, q.N
    FROM(
        SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
    ) q(N)
    CROSS JOIN(
        SELECT DISTINCT reporting_date / 100 FROM #temp
    ) y(N)
)
,GroupedByQtr AS(
    SELECT
        *,
        qtr = (reporting_date % 100 -1) / 3 + 1,
        yr = reporting_date / 100,
        ss = SUM(interest_payment) OVER(PARTITION BY (reporting_date / 100), ((reporting_date % 100 -1) / 3 + 1)),
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY (reporting_date / 100), ((reporting_date % 100 -1) / 3 + 1) ORDER BY reporting_date)
    FROM #temp
)
SELECT 
    reporting_date = 'Q' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(1), q.qtr) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), q.yr),
    interest_payment = ISNULL(g.ss, 0),
    balance = ISNULL(g.balance, 0)
FROM quarters q
LEFT JOIN GroupedByQtr g
    ON g.qtr = q.qtr
    AND g.yr = q.yr
    AND g.rn = 1
```

**RESULT**

```
reporting_date interest_payment balance
-------------- ---------------- -----------
Q1 - 2004      60               10
Q2 - 2004      150              30
Q3 - 2004      70               60
Q4 - 2004      0                0
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback ,could please let me know why do we have 3 union statement and in case if i have group more column do i need to add more unions statement

Comment: No, the `UNION ALL` is to generate the `4 quarters`.