# How to get monthly and quarterly data for a team

Tags: sql

I want to be able to generate a report the shows the current month of submitted surveys compared to what the total quarter of surveys has.  I need the statement to be able to add the monthly amounts each month the report is exported.  Anyone know how to accomplish this?

```
SELECT UA.FirstName
    ,UA.LastName
    ,COUNT(S.Year) AS TotalStudies
    ,(SELECT COUNT(S.Year) 
    FROM ParentInfo P
    LEFT JOIN Survey S ON P.SurveyId=S.SurveyId
    LEFT JOIN CooperationLevel CL ON P.SurveyId=CL.SurveyID
    LEFT JOIN SurveyAccess SA ON P.SurveyId=SA.SurveyId
    LEFT JOIN UserAccount UA ON SA.UserId=UA.UserId
    WHERE S.Year=Year(GETDATE()) 
    AND (CL.CIOISCooperation=1 OR CL.CIOISPartialCooperation=1) 
    AND  UA.UserId in (73699)
    GROUP BY UA.FirstName,UA.LastName,SA.UserId) AS Cooperation
    ,(SELECT COUNT(S.Year) AS NoCooperation
    FROM ParentInfo P
    LEFT JOIN Survey S ON P.SurveyId=S.SurveyId
    LEFT JOIN CooperationLevel CL ON P.SurveyId=CL.SurveyID
    LEFT JOIN SurveyAccess SA ON P.SurveyId=SA.SurveyId
    LEFT JOIN UserAccount UA ON SA.UserId=UA.UserId
    WHERE S.Year=Year(GETDATE()) 
    AND ((CL.CIOISCooperation=0 AND CL.CIOISPartialCooperation=0) OR CL.CIOISCooperation IS NULL AND CL.CIOISPartialCooperation IS NULL) 
    AND  UA.UserId in (73699)
    GROUP BY SA.UserId) AS NoCooperation
    FROM ParentInfo P
    LEFT JOIN Survey S ON P.SurveyId=S.SurveyId
    LEFT JOIN CooperationLevel CL ON P.SurveyId=CL.SurveyID
    LEFT JOIN SurveyAccess SA ON P.SurveyId=SA.SurveyId
    LEFT JOIN UserAccount UA ON SA.UserId=UA.UserId
    WHERE S.Year=Year(GETDATE()) 
    AND  UA.UserId in (73699)
    GROUP BY UA.FirstName,UA.LastName,SA.UserId
```

The current query only gives the individual surveys not the aggregate.

Comment: You will need to post a sample of your tables. Looking at your goal, I would take a guess that you can achieve it with 2 subqueries of JOIN and Group together by SurveyID

Comment: I was able to get what I am looking for with this query (above has been edited), however I only want the quarters and not the year information @Isaiah3015

Comment: Additionally, when I tried to add all userIDs the total surveys gave the yearly amount not the amount for each userID

Comment: Please edit what you need. Your comment and your post are completely 2 different goals. Perhaps it's best to ask question multiple post, proving pieces of problems in order to actually get somewhere. What's clear is your goal in this comment. Here's a way for you to get the quarters of year. Create columns that separate the quarters and you sum up based on those quarters.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141100/how-to-get-quarter-from-a-date-in-tsql