# Finding Quarter of year in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database that contains financial info of banks.

This is the table structure. For the sake of simplicity I have made `Assets` int.

```
create table dbo.BankInfo
(
     id int, 
     asofdate date, 
     Assets int
)

insert into dbo.BankInfo Values(1,'2018-01-31',100)
insert into dbo.BankInfo Values(1,'2017-10-31',200)
insert into dbo.BankInfo Values(1,'2017-07-31',300)
insert into dbo.BankInfo Values(1,'2017-04-30',400)
insert into dbo.BankInfo Values(1,'2017-01-31',40)
insert into dbo.BankInfo Values(1,'2016-10-31',20)

insert into dbo.BankInfo Values(2,'2016-12-31 00:00:00',100)
insert into dbo.BankInfo Values(2,'2017-03-31 00:00:00',200)
insert into dbo.BankInfo Values(2,'2017-06-30 00:00:00',300)
insert into dbo.BankInfo Values(2,'2017-09-30 00:00:00',400)
insert into dbo.BankInfo Values(2,'2017-12-31 00:00:00',300)
insert into dbo.BankInfo Values(2,'2016-03-31 00:00:00',400)
```

I have another table that contains info of each bank's Fiscal yearenddate

```
create table dbo.yearenddate
(
     id int, 
     enddate date
)

insert into dbo.yearenddate values(1,'2018-01-31  00:00:00')
insert into dbo.yearenddate values(2,'2017-06-30 00:00:00')
```

I want to look at `dbo.BankInfo`, get the Fiscalyearenddate for each bank and set the Quarter (Qtr=4) and others follow the same pattern

This is how the output looks like. I am unable to do this by rank.

```
create table dbo.outputqtr
(
     id int, 
     asofdate date, 
     Assets int, 
     qtr smallint
)

insert into dbo.outputqtr Values(1,'2018-01-31',100,4)
insert into dbo.outputqtr Values(1,'2017-10-31',200,3)
insert into dbo.outputqtr Values(1,'2017-07-31',300,2)
insert into dbo.outputqtr Values(1,'2017-04-30',400,1)
insert into dbo.outputqtr Values(1,'2017-01-31',40,4)
insert into dbo.outputqtr Values(1,'2016-10-31',20,3)

insert into dbo.outputqtr Values(2,'2016-12-31 00:00:00',100,2)
insert into dbo.outputqtr Values(2,'2017-03-31 00:00:00',200,3)
insert into dbo.outputqtr Values(2,'2017-06-30 00:00:00',300,4)
insert into dbo.outputqtr Values(2,'2017-09-30 00:00:00',400,1)
insert into dbo.outputqtr Values(2,'2017-12-31 00:00:00',300,2)
insert into dbo.outputqtr Values(2,'2016-03-31 00:00:00',400,3)
```

The query I have is

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
       WHEN qtrr = 4 THEN 4
       ELSE DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, MONTH(asofdate)
                              ORDER BY asofdate DESC) 
    END AS qtr
FROM
    (SELECT
         t.*, y.enddate,
         CASE 
            WHEN AsofDate = enddate THEN 4
            ELSE 1
         END AS qtrr
     FROM
         dbo.BankInfo t
     LEFT JOIN
         dbo.yearenddate y ON y.id = t.id AND t.asofdate = y.enddate) t
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Quarter from a date in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141100/how-to-get-quarter-from-a-date-in-tsql)

Comment: From the dupe, this is what you need I think: SELECT DATEPART(QUARTER, @date)

Comment: No its not a duplicate. You can use that if you that December is always 4th quarter

Comment: @user2726975, please explain your expected result. Why bank `2` with end-of-year date `2017-06-30` has result `1` in the row `2,'2017-06-30 00:00:00',300,1`? Shouldn't it be 4? Please explain each line in the expected result.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I am sorry , you are right, I just edited the expected result table.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like all you need is to calculate the number of months from the anchor date from the `yearenddate` table and then convert that number into quarters.

Examine intermediate results of the formula below to understand how it works.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @BankInfo TABLE
(
    id int, 
    asofdate date, 
    Assets int
);

insert into @BankInfo Values(1,'2018-01-31',100)
insert into @BankInfo Values(1,'2017-10-31',200)
insert into @BankInfo Values(1,'2017-07-31',300)
insert into @BankInfo Values(1,'2017-04-30',400)
insert into @BankInfo Values(1,'2017-01-31',40)
insert into @BankInfo Values(1,'2016-10-31',20)

insert into @BankInfo Values(2,'2016-12-31',100)
insert into @BankInfo Values(2,'2017-03-31',200)
insert into @BankInfo Values(2,'2017-06-30',300)
insert into @BankInfo Values(2,'2017-09-30',400)
insert into @BankInfo Values(2,'2017-12-31',300)
insert into @BankInfo Values(2,'2016-03-31',400)

DECLARE @yearenddate TABLE
(
    id int, 
    enddate date
)

insert into @yearenddate values(1,'2018-01-31')
insert into @yearenddate values(2,'2017-06-30')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    B.id
    ,B.asofdate
    ,B.Assets
    ,(DATEDIFF(month, EOY.enddate, B.asofdate) / 3 + 399) % 4 + 1 AS qtr
FROM
    @BankInfo AS B
    INNER JOIN @yearenddate AS EOY ON B.id = EOY.id
;
```

**Result**

```
+----+------------+--------+-----+
| id |  asofdate  | Assets | qtr |
+----+------------+--------+-----+
|  1 | 2018-01-31 |    100 |   4 |
|  1 | 2017-10-31 |    200 |   3 |
|  1 | 2017-07-31 |    300 |   2 |
|  1 | 2017-04-30 |    400 |   1 |
|  1 | 2017-01-31 |     40 |   4 |
|  1 | 2016-10-31 |     20 |   3 |
|  2 | 2016-12-31 |    100 |   2 |
|  2 | 2017-03-31 |    200 |   3 |
|  2 | 2017-06-30 |    300 |   4 |
|  2 | 2017-09-30 |    400 |   1 |
|  2 | 2017-12-31 |    300 |   2 |
|  2 | 2016-03-31 |    400 |   3 |
+----+------------+--------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query should give you expected results.

```
;with CTE AS 
     (
         SELECT t.*, y.enddate,
        datediff(MONTH, AsofDate,   enddate)%12 QTRY                              
         FROM dbo.BankInfo t   CROSS APPLY  dbo.yearenddate y 
         where y.id = t.id
     )
     select ID,AsOfDate,Assets, CASE WHEN QTRY=0 THEN 4 WHEN QTRY<0 THEN ABS(QTRY)/3 ELSE 4-QTRY/3 END AS QTR
     FROM CTE
```